# JavaScript Traffic light array with timer

Tags: javascript

I have created a traffic light simulation(array) however i can't figure out where to put the timer. I know how to add the timer but i don't know where in my code do i put the timer.  please help.
Thanks.

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Task 3</h1>

<p>This is my Traffic Light script</p>

<img id="light" src="./assets/red.jpg">

<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>

<script>
var list = [
    "./assets/red.jpg",
    "./assets/redamber.jpg",
    "./assets/green.jpg",
    "./assets/amber.jpg"
];

var index = 0;

function changeLights() {
    index = index + 1;

    if (index == list.length) index = 0;

    var image = document.getElementById('light');
    image.src=list[index];
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is javaScript not Java

Comment: if you need changing the color use like that `setInterval(function (){
  changeLights();
   },1000);` every one second it will be change or tell what is the use of the timer ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `SettTimeout` function you can do that. `SetTimout` function delays the execution of the script by provided interval.

```js
var list = [
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Solid_red.png",
    "./assets/redamber.jpg",
    "https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bullet-green.png",
    "./assets/amber.jpg"
];

var index = 0;




function changeLights() {
setTimeout(function(){
 // your code here.
      index = index + 1;

    if (index == list.length) index = 0;
  
  console.log(index);

    var image = document.getElementById('light');
    image.innerHtml=list[index];
},1000);
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Task 3</h1>

<p>This is my Traffic Light script</p>



<img id="light" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Solid_red.pn">

<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to add a timer onlaod:

```
<body onload="trafficTimer(2000);">

function trafficTimer(timer) {
    setInterval(function() { changeLights(); }, timer);
};
```

This will change light each 2s

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the suggested

```
setInterval(function () { changeLights(); }, 1000);
```

you could use the function as callback directly

```
setInterval(changeLights, 1000);
```